# Какие изменения вопроса не влияют на отображение последнего редактирующего?

Tags: поддержка, правки, ревизии

Тред: [Есть ли бесплатные лицензии IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate для активных участников Stackoverflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7989/15479)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на странице ревизий (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7989/revisions) видим, что после этого много действия над постом производилось.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие действия влияют на отображаемого последнего редактирующего? Только фактические правки текста/заголовка/меток? Блокировки, закрытия и т.п. не влияют?

**UPD:**

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в самом вопросе нету этого:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только в списке ревизий есть:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конечно, не влияют. Они же не редактируют вопрос

Comment: Я думаю, здесь ответа не дождешься. Надо на MSE писать. И поиском там сначала пройтись.